# How to avoid out of memory when I start a second animation drawable

Tags: android, animation, out-of-memory

I am a newbie in Android and now I am totally lost... could you give me some hints with my code?
I am trying to run a stop motion animation using AnimationDrawable from some of the images that I previously copied to the res folder of the project. The images to be used in the animation are selected in runtime, so I used addFrame to include them. When user push a button the animation starts successfully with the selected images. Then the user is asked for select new images and again, after pushing the button, the new animation should start. The problem is that then it causes OUT OF MEMORY errors. These errors do not happens in the first animation, so it seems that I am wasting the memory of the phone (or emulator) with the successive animations. How could I release the memory used in the first animation before starting the second one?

I tried using ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle(); but then I can not use the image for the second animation.

Any suggestions?

This is the relevant part of my code, I guess:

```
int globeId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(resname1, "drawable",
                this.getPackageName());

        animation.addFrame(this.getResources().getDrawable(globeId), velocidad);
        int globeId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(resname2, "drawable",
                this.getPackageName());
        animation.addFrame(this.getResources().getDrawable(globeId), velocidad);
        ...

        animation.setOneShot(true);
        imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
        animation.start();
```

And this is the error:

```
   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1251K, 5% free 59812K/62471K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 61062K/62471K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
   I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 5119532-byte allocation
   D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 3% free 61052K/62471K, paused 4ms, total 6ms
   E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 5119532-byte allocation.
```

Comment: `could you give me some hints with my code?` not without the code. Post relevant excerpts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @f43nd1r, I added the relevant code and excerpts I guess